# Remove stock photos from iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, appium

I have a mobile test suite which targets both android and iOS devices. However in the interest of having a similar environment for android and iOS i wish to remove the stock photos in the iOS devices created by the simulator.

Is there any reliable way of removing stock photos from the iOS simulator through the command line? In such a manner that it can be repeated for each run of the test suite?

Answer (score 2):

All Simulator photo data is stored in `path/to/[Simulator UDID]/data/Media/DCIM/` and `path/to/[Simulator UDID]/data/Media/PhotoData/`.  You could write a script that gets all of the Simulator UDIDs (or specific your own) of photos to remove.  You can use `xcrun simctl list` or `instruments -s devices` to list all of the currently connected device UDIDs.

Here's a small ruby script which should fit your needs:

```
simulatorList = []

# Get all of the simulator UUIDs from Xcode
rawSimulatorList = `xcrun simctl list`
rawSimulatorList.each_line do |line|
    if line.start_with?("    ")
        simulator = line.strip

        # Ignore any simulators that aren't working
        if !simulator.include?("unavailable")

            # Extract the UUID
            uuid = simulator.match(/\([A-Z0-9\-]+\)/)[0]
            uuid = uuid.gsub("(","")
            uuid = uuid.gsub(")","")

            # Extract the device name
            deviceName = simulator.split(' ')[0] + " " + simulator.split(' ')[1]
            device = { "name" => deviceName, "uuid" => uuid }
            simulatorList.push(device)
        end
    end
end

simulatorList.each do |simulator|
    `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/#{simulator['udid']}/data/Media/DCIM/`
    `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/#{simulator['udid']}/data/Media/PhotoData/`
end
```

Ruby is not my first language and this script was adapted from Ian Spence's [reset.rb script](https://gist.github.com/ecnepsnai/6dc6ecbb2dfa1922f826).  Your milage with this may vary.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, atleast not with appium. Appium seems to reset the device after the script has removed the photos.

Comment: @netbrain Did not know you were using Appium.  Will try to find another solution for you.

Comment: There are some typos in the script (`udid` should be `uuid`).